# Tabel is not creating While install custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, database, table

I have created a custom module. But When Install it does not create any table. And It does not show any error.  But It makes a link in admin panel. When I click on it, It shows error like

> **'custom_magento.cm_fabric_icons' doesn't exist**

.

**sql setup file.**

```
$installer = $this;
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('fabric_icons/icons'))
    ->addColumn('icons_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'identity' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ), 'Entity id')
    ->addColumn("title", Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array( 'nullable' => true),"Title")
    ->addColumn("slim_fit_title", Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array( 'nullable' => true),"Slim Fit Title")
    ->addColumn("slim_fit_image", Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array( 'nullable' => true),"Slim Fit Image")
    ->addColumn("normal_fit_title", Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array( 'nullable' => true),"Normal Fit Title")
    ->addColumn("normal_fit_image", Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array( 'nullable' => true),"Normal Fit Image")
    ->setComment("Fabric Icons");
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

**data setup file,**

```
$installer = $this;
$model = Mage::getModel('fabric_icons/icons');
$dataRows = array(
                                array(
                                "icons_id" => "1"
                                ,"title" => "Tool Design Icons"
                                ,"slim_fit_title" => "Slim Fit"
                                ,"slim_fit_image" => "m_normal.png"
                                ,"normal_fit_title" => "Normal Fit"
                                ,"normal_fit_image" => "m_normal_1.png"
                                )
              );
foreach ($dataRows as $data) {
    $model->setData($data)->setOrigData()->save();
}
```

Comment: can you please tell,the name of sql,data sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Pradeep Sanku](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44519/how-to-re-install-custom-module-in-local-with-sql-script/44544#44544) Answer match for your needs.

Delete **Package_module** record from the **`core_resource Table`** and refresh your current working script your browser.Script will executed once again and table will automatically regenerated into your database.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely causes are:

1. Your sql files are named incorrectly.
2. The configuration in your config.xml is incorrect.
3. Your module existed in core_resource before you added the information to the script.

I can't really comment on the first two as you didn't include that information. You can confirm if it's the 3rd by looking for your module name in core_resource. If the row exists, you can remove it, clear the cache and refresh to attempt to re-trigger the install script.

Comment: I did not see the third comment. If I saw, I would accept it as answer. +1 vote for your answer.